# Usage of reflexive pronoun ("les") in "¿Por qué no les dio Lupe el dinero a Uds.?"

Tags: gramática, pronombres

> ¿Por qué no les dio Lupe el dinero a Uds.?

In English, this sentence means:

> Why didn't Lupe give money to you?

Why do we need to put "les" in this sentence?

Comment: You can drop it, because it refers to *ustedes*. We can say *¿Por qué no dio Lupe el dinero a ustedes?* This is the same as saying *¿Por qué no les dio Lupe el dinero?* (= a ustedes)

Comment: Also, not a reflexive pronoun but an indirect object pronoun.

Comment: Note: I've just realised the question above is different because the usage of pronouns with another pronoun ("a **Uds**.") and with a noun ("a su **novia**") are governed by different rules. For more info, see my answer on [Why use "-las" in "esperándolas"?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/17192/why-use-las-in-esper%C3%A1ndolas). According to what I state there, you can't drop the "les" here because Uds. is a personal pronoun, but I cannot tell how natural your sentence without the "les" sounds because I seldom hear anyone use Uds. at all in Spain. (1/2)

Comment: Anyway, it may sound okay here because the verb and the pronoun are far away from each other. If you put them closer, it doesn't sound that well anymore: *¿Por qué nos les dio a Uds. el dinero Lupe?* sounds okey (maybe a bit unusual but not agrammatical), while *¿Por qué no dio a Uds. el dinero Lupe?* feels plain wrong to me. (2/2)

Comment: @Ustanak Check out my previous comment. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yashirq - Note the definite article ("el") before "dinero". "Dinero" wouldn't normally take an article (no me queda dinero = I have no money left), so adding an article makes it a specific amount of money and/or for a specific purpose. Therefore, your English sentence should read "Why didn't Lupe give **the** money to you?"

Comment: Even more idiomatic 'why didn't Lupe give you the money?'

Comment: @Yay I agree, but *¿por qué no dio a ustedes el dinero Lupe?* seems awful but it makes sense. To me looks like an old usage of Spanish, but it still works. — I have an answer in mind. I'll post it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ¿Por qué no les dio Lupe el dinero a Uds.?

The majority of the native speakers I talk to say it sounds better and clearer with the "*les*", which, by the way, is an **[object pronoun](https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/spanish/parts-of-speech/direct-and-indirect-objects)**, and is already indicated by *a Ustedes.*  Deleting "*les*" might possibly render the sentence agramatical.

Please take note that "*les*" is **not reflexive** because it refers to "you (plural)", and Lupe was the subject of the sentence.

Comment: @Gandalf I'm tempted to edit the question title to *Why use "les" in "¿Por qué no les dio Lupe el dinero a Uds.?"?*  but that would invalidate a big part of your answer. Besides that, I *don't* think you can drop it (see question linked in the comments for references). Not only does it sound worse, but it also makes the sentence aggramatical.

Comment: @Yay I agree that it sounds better with the "les", and including _a Ustedes_ sounds a little clumsy, but I don't know what do to with this post. I am being criticized for including material about the reflexive, but I honestly believed the OP had problems that needed to be addressed concerning that topic as it is often misunderstood. Now I have a big fat -1 sitting on an accepted answer, and that irks me because I cannot even delete it if I want to.

Comment: @Gandalf Don't take it personally. The point is, even if you feel the OP would appreciate an explanation on a certain topic, answering something that wasn't really asked is problematic for several reasons: it hinders marking future duplicates (should it be a duplicate of the *question* or the *answer*?) as well as finding information on the topic, and it makes it less "upvotable", because by up-voting it it wouldn't be clear why it's being up-voted (do up-voters agree with the real answer or are they expressing they think it is a good idea to veer off the main topic of the question?). (+)

Comment: (+) If you feel the OP wouldn't be satisfied with just answering their real question, you can always add a few links and/or encourage them to ask a different question (which I don't think is necessary here because the "reflexive se" has already been adressed before). I recommend you edit the last part out and save it in case someone really asks something about "reflexive se". I think that would revert your current vote outcome.

Comment: @Yay Copy that, and understood. Done as you suggested, and many Thanks! That was an extremely astute analysis of the situation.